# How to debug fatal signal 11 code 2 in UnityMain?

Tags: unity, android

i have searched for the

> fatal signal caused by Render or GxDriver, FlashMuller in unity forum
>   says it's google play

the error:

```
08-03 14:59:47.503 32020-32092/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0xcbe8dffc in tid 32092 (UnityMain), pid 32020 (com.tuo3.alive)
08-03 14:59:47.533 32121-32121/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    Build fingerprint: 'OnePlus/OnePlus5T/OnePlus5T:8.1.0/OPM1.171019.011/1807181208:user/release-keys'
    Revision: '0'
    ABI: 'arm'
    pid: 32020, tid: 32092, name: UnityMain  >>> com.tuo3.alive <<<
08-03 14:59:47.544 32121-32121/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
        #00 pc 000575d0  /system/lib/libc.so (je_arena_tcache_fill_small+71)
        #01 pc 00077919  /system/lib/libc.so (je_tcache_alloc_small_hard+16)
        #02 pc 00058fc7  /system/lib/libc.so (je_arena_palloc+1650)
        #03 pc 00069bd1  /system/lib/libc.so (imemalign+1164)
        #04 pc 0006d373  /system/lib/libc.so (je_memalign+26)
        #05 pc 001d6f18  /data/app/com.tuo3.alive-VZWALBY70nH_dSDIQa_rKA==/lib/arm/libunity.so (UnityDefaultAllocator<LowLevelAllocator>::Allocate(unsigned int, int)+24)
        #06 pc 001da888  /data/app/com.tuo3.alive-VZWALBY70nH_dSDIQa_rKA==/lib/arm/libunity.so (MemoryManager::Allocate(unsigned int, unsigned int, MemLabelId const&, AllocateOptions, char const*, int)+852)
        #07 pc 001da254  /data/app/com.tuo3.alive-VZWALBY70nH_dSDIQa_rKA==/lib/arm/libunity.so (malloc_internal(unsigned int, unsigned int, MemLabelId const&, AllocateOptions, char const*, int)+128)
        #08 pc 00193bc8  /data/app/com.tuo3.alive-VZWALBY70nH_dSDIQa_rKA==/lib/arm/libunity.so (core::StringStorageDefault<char>::assign(char const*, unsigned int)+180)
        #09 pc 00a350bc  /data/app/com.tuo3.alive-VZWALBY70nH_dSDIQa_rKA==/lib/arm/libunity.so (__gnu_cxx::hashtable<std::pair<core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char>> const, ZipCentralDirectory::PathDescriptor>, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char>>, __gnu_cxx::hash<core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char>>>, std::_Select1st<__gnu_cxx::hash>, std::equal_to<core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char>>>, std::allocator, <ZipCentralDirectory::
        #10 pc 00a34adc  /data/app/com.tuo3.alive-VZWALBY70nH_dSDIQa_rKA==/lib/arm/libunity.so (_ZZN19ZipCentralDirectory20readCentralDirectoryEvEN3$_08__invokeERK15FileSystemEntryR12FileAccessorPKcRKN3zip4CDFDEPv+508)
        #11 pc 00a38160  /data/app/com.tuo3.alive-VZWALBY70nH_dSDIQa_rKA==/lib/arm/libunity.so (zip::CentralDirectory::Enumerate(bool (*)(FileSystemEntry const&, FileAccessor&, char const*, zip::CDFD const&, void*), void*)+804)
        #12 pc 00a348d0  /data/app/com.tuo3.alive-VZWALBY70nH_dSDIQa_rKA==/lib/arm/libunity.so (ZipCentralDirectory::readCentralDirectory()+20)
        #13 pc 00a26630  /data/app/com.tuo3.alive-VZWALBY70nH_dSDIQa_rKA==/lib/arm/libunity.so (apkAddCentralDirectory+84)
        #14 pc 00a19074  /data/app/com.tuo3.alive-VZWALBY70nH_dSDIQa_rKA==/lib/arm/libunity.so (Mount(char const*)+84)
        #15 pc 00a090dc  /data/app/com.tuo3.alive-VZWALBY70nH_dSDIQa_rKA==/lib/arm/libunity.so (UnityInitApplication()+216)
        #16 pc 00a0a660  /data/app/com.tuo3.alive-VZWALBY70nH_dSDIQa_rKA==/lib/arm/libunity.so (UnityPlayerLoop()+264)
        #17 pc 00a0cc68  /data/app/com.tuo3.alive-VZWALBY70nH_dSDIQa_rKA==/lib/arm/libunity.so (nativeRender(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+228)
        #18 pc 000114cb  /data/app/com.tuo3.alive-VZWALBY70nH_dSDIQa_rKA==/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x10000)

[More discussion][2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put too much files in `StreammingAssets` which lead to apk contains 2w+ files, then crash.

[More debug detail](https://answer.uwa4d.com/question/5b5f0a7b1e88b37d34e651a1)

Comment: Glad to see that you solved the problem! Don't forget to [mark this as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) - it helps others who may run into the same or similar problems.